# Unable to run logit model/ logistic regression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a logistic regression. The data has been scrubbed and categorical variables change to dummies however when i run the code i get an error message from the "statsmodels" package outside of my code and not sure how to correct in this case.

A friend of mine ran the same code and he got an output (print screen below), as i'm using spyder with python 3.6 he thinks it might be a version issue - he is using python 3.5

I've got the code below. Any ideas on how to fix it or how better to run a logistic regression is appreciated.

error message i'm getting is in statsmodels library: 
*File "C:\Users\sebas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 2405, in llr_pvalue
    return stats.chisqprob(self.llr, self.df_model)*

**AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'chisqprob'**

thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rc("font", size=14)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)


################################################################################

## Logistic regression

###############################################################################


data = pd.read_csv(r"log reg test Lending club 2007-2011 car only.csv")
#data = data.dropna()
print(data.shape)
##print(list(data.columns))

print(data['Distressed'].value_counts()) ## number of defaulted car loans is binary

sns.countplot(x='Distressed', data=data, palette='hls')
plt.show ## confrim dependent variable is binary


##basic numerical analysis of variables to check feasibility for model
## we will need to create dummy variables for strings
#print(data.groupby('Distressed').mean()) ##numerical variable means
#print(data.groupby('grade').mean()) ## string variable means
#print(data.groupby('sub_grade').mean())
#print(data.groupby('emp_length').mean())
#print(data.groupby('home_ownership').mean())

##testing for nulls in dataset
print(data.isnull().sum()) 
scrub_data=data.drop(['mths_since_last_delinq'],1) ## this variable is not statistically significant

print('Here is the logit model data')
print(scrub_data.isnull().sum()) ## removed records of missing info, sample still sufficiently large

print(list(scrub_data.columns))
print(scrub_data.head())

##convert categorical variables to dummies completed in csv file

X=scrub_data.ix[:,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22)].values
y=scrub_data.ix[:,0].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.3, random_state=25) 

LogReg=LogisticRegression()
LogReg.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=LogReg.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))

print('alternative method using RFE')

#y=['Distressed']
#x=[i for i in data if i not in y]
#print(y)
#print(x)
#print(data.info())

## check for independance between features

correlation=sns.heatmap(data.corr()) ## heatmap showing correlations of the variables
print(correlation)

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
#logreg = LogisticRegression()
#rfe = RFE(logreg,10)
#rfe=rfe.fit(x,y)
#print(rfe.support_)
#print(rfe.ranking_)

import statsmodels.api as sm
logit_model=sm.Logit(y,X)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

Comment: Have you tried installing Python 3.5 and running your code with it to see what happens? Sounds like your friend might be onto something, and you should investigate that lead first.

Comment: Please mention whats the error.Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: that's a version compatibility problem, see https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3931#issuecomment-365384886 for workaround until the next statsmodels release

Comment: I've updated the error message i get into the query. couldn't get python 3.5 to work as the version in spyder so i downloaded anaconda2 which has python2.7 and i get  the same error message

Comment: SUCCESS! User333700 your two lines of workaround code fixed it!! Thanks everyone for the inputs

Answer (score 1):

The error can be fixed by assigning the missing function back into the `scipy.stats` namespace as shown below:

```
from scipy import stats

stats.chisqprob = lambda chisq, df: stats.chi2.sf(chisq, df)
```

Comment: Dear Tomerikoo , What have you edited in the post?Please clarify